# PostgreSQL Probabilities: EXPLAIN on CREATE INDEX

Tags: postgresql, indexing, probability

I am using PostgreSQL to compute empirical probability density functions for pairs of variables across all my data. I am trying to determine if/when it is more effective to index before computing the PDF. I run EXPLAIN CREATE INDEX like,

```
EXPLAIN CREATE INDEX AB ON xrootd ("F.mName", "F.mOpenTime");
CREATE INDEX AB ON xrootd ("F.mName", "F.mOpenTime");
```

But PSQL complains,

```
psql:sql/stats.sql:3: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INDEX"
LINE 2: EXPLAIN CREATE INDEX AB ON xrootd ("F.mName", "F.mOpenTime")...
```

Is there a better way of doing anything I am trying to do? At the very least, I would like to know if constructing the indexes is useful. I have a lot of variable and a lot of data, so speeding this up is crucial.

Checking the cost of CREATE INDEX would be able to tell me if make the index is too expensive for the gain of using it.

Comment: Strange question. IMHO there is no way to estimate the cost of *creating* an index. There is a way to determine the cost of the query with/without the index, though. [and, normally the data model is considered more or less static, so this would be more like a design problem]

Comment: I use SQL for these kinds of things (smaller data in the past) because I haven't found anything faster than SQL for counting and grouping. This data is just obnoxious and has tons of variables

Answer (score 4):

There is no `EXPLAIN CREATE INDEX`, as `EXPLAIN` only works for `SELECTs` and DML queries (`INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE`).

What you are probably looking for is called hypothetical indexes. There is a PostgreSQL extension for that: https://github.com/dalibo/hypopg

Comment: this is really interesting, thank you, 
PS: the extension was moved to this repo: https://github.com/HypoPG/hypopg